# How can I Identify the dll being referenced causing ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I currently have a large project and it is very difficult to identify the source of this warnings which is quite annoying.  In our case we need to compile tih x64 since we have specific dependencies on 64bit libraries.  Additionally attempts to disable this warning by adding it to the ignore list have failed.

Other SO questions discuss this warning with respect to satellite assemblies, but I don't have resource files.
[ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365616/alink-warning-al1073-referenced-assembly-mscorlib-dll-targets-a-different-p)

One particular issue we have is that we have external partners and many nuget package references so it is not easy to identify the source of the problem.

Are there any tools available to help pinpoint the issue or any recommendations on what I can do to pin down the issue?

I am currently using .NET core 3.0 and VS 2019.  Note that there are other SO questions on this issue, but they make reference to much older versions of .NEt and some state that the warning goes away with various combinations of VS and  .NET 4.5+

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the DLLs by removing all .cs files, and then adding/removing dependencies (package references) directly from the .csproj.  This helps to quite easily isolate the problem.